# NextJS as a backend JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I got confuse while searching top JS backend framework then I found NextJS is one of the top list, I thought nextjs is just a simplify of CRA and still need like nodejs as the backend. Back to my confusion, so when we normally create a full JS app we will need frontend and backend tech like (nodejs + reactjs) so with this nextjs we can make a app just with nextjs ? **sorry for my bad English

Comment: NextJs requires NodeJs it is not an independent language.  NextJs just renders your react app on the server side making it easier for search engines to index your site and is better for seo. You would still write your backend code with NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, NextJS is basically React on wheels and has NodeJS built-in. It has lots of other features built-in so you need almost zero-configuration to build a full-stack app.

If you have 10 minutes to spare, take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtgbaKBhdkk)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially NextJS is a full-stack framework. Which means that developers can write both front-end and back-end code in a single environment. It can provide multiple benefits among various use cases. Which can be things like seo optimization, image optimization or quickly switching between different rendering methods (SSR, CSR, ISR or SSG).

As for your question "Can we make an app just with nextjs ?", you certainly can but it depends heavily on what type your app is.

Answer (score 0):

React still uses Node under the hood. However, it has no backend routing system without using something like express. Next.js on the other is a full stack framework in which you can build an app without any other frameworks. Other than that Next.js uses SSR vs React client rendering and is overall more complete including a built in router and other helper functions.